# Entity Framework OrderBy with specified Guid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, guid

I am attempting to retrieved randomized records from an Azure SQL database using Entity Framework. I know that if you specify:

```
OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
```

that it will randomize the results of the query.

However, If I specify a Guid:

```
OrderBy(x => guidVariable)
```

It doesn't randomize the results.

The reason that I want to do this is to be able to page the randomized results with out the randomization being changed with every call:

(I am using a repository pattern that returns an IQueryable)

```
   recordRepository.FetchByIds(Ids)                                                                                   
                   .OrderBy(x => randomizeKey)
                   .Skip(seedIndex)
                   .Take(pageSize)
                   .ToList();
```

Repository Code:

```
 return Context.Entities.Include("Path")
                        .Include("Path")
                        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Am I correct in assuming that Entity Framework interprets the Guid.NewGuid() and has SQL server generate its own? Is there a way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is `guidVariable`?

Comment: A specified Guid variable

Comment: Is it predefined? If you don't create a new `Guid` every time you retrieve the items, it will always sort them based on this pre-existing `Guid` ofcourse. So it will always return the same sequence. The thing about your first method is that it will create a new `Guid` each time it is called, and thus randomize it every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy(x => randomizeKey)` will be same for each item, so you will get the same sequence at the end

e.g.

```
new[] {"3", "1", "6"}.OrderBy(x=>5); // results "3", "1", "6"
```

If you need to get same sequence try [using Random Number Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with same seed

```
Random r1 = new Random(4);

var result1 = new[] {"3", "1", "6"}.OrderBy(x=>r1.Next());

Random r2 = new Random(4);

var result2 = new[] {"3", "1", "6"}.OrderBy(x=>r2.Next());
```

you will get same sequence for result1 and result2

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess that I was assuming that the guid was forcing a different evaluation with every comparison, especially comparing against an int. Now I understand the algorithm...